# Why is net command for creating new local account not working as expected in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, cmd, windows-8.1, user-accounts

The problem is simple. When I type next command in elevated command prompt new user that can log in should be created:

```
net user UserName UserPass /ADD
```

After that command execute I should be able to start process and to log into machine as that user:

```
runas /user:UserName "cmd.exe"
```

After typing in password for user message I get is:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - cmd.exe
299: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.
```

But command is successful if I run it with /noprofile option. Also user created like this is not able to log on computer, log in fails with message:

```
User profile Service service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded.
```

OS is Windows 8.1 (original not pirate version) upgraded from Windows 8. I suspect that this is some Windows configuration error so it would be nice if one could point me in right direction.

Comment: Have you had a look at this http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/case-of-the-user-service-service-failed-the-logon/

Comment: I couldn't find that specific file but listed there, but after seeing your comment here I repeated whole process with more effort and it all worked out finally. The problem was series of .sqm files in:
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\SQM\sqmdata*
Thank you for pointing me in right direction! You can post it as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link is very likely to direct you towards identifying any files that might be causing this error. 
http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/case-of-the-user-service-service-failed-the-logon/